# Как добавить звук срабатывания будильника?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qml, qtquick

Пишу будильник на QML, нужно добавить звук срабатывания будильника, когда дата и время будильника доходит до системной(в общем звук срабатывания при обычной работе будильника). Как мне это сделать?

Здесь лежат будильники(в том числе и добавленные):

**AlarmModel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

// Populate the model with some sample data.
ListModel {
    id: alarmModel

    ListElement {
        hour: 6
        minute: 1
        day: 3
        month: 8
        year: 2021
        activated: true
        label: "Wake up"
        repeat: true
        daysToRepeat: [
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 0; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 1; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 2; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 3; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 4; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 5; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 6; repeat: false }
        ]
    }
    ListElement {
        hour: 6
        minute: 0
        day: 3
        month: 8
        year: 2021
        activated: true
        label: "Wake up"
        repeat: true
        daysToRepeat: [
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 0; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 1; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 2; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 3; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 4; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 5; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 6; repeat: false }
        ]
    }
    ListElement {
        hour: 7
        minute: 0
        day: 3
        month: 8
        year: 2021
        activated: false
        label: "Exercise"
        repeat: true
        daysToRepeat: [
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 0; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 1; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 2; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 3; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 4; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 5; repeat: true },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 6; repeat: true }
        ]
    }
    ListElement {
        hour: 5
        minute: 15
        day: 1
        month: 9
        year: 2021
        activated: true
        label: ""
        repeat: false
        daysToRepeat: [
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 0; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 1; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 2; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 3; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 4; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 5; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 6; repeat: false }
        ]
    }
    ListElement {
        hour: 5
        minute: 45
        day: 3
        month: 4
        year: 2021
        activated: false
        label: ""
        repeat: false
        daysToRepeat: [
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 0; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 1; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 2; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 3; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 4; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 5; repeat: false },
            ListElement { dayOfWeek: 6; repeat: false }
        ]
    }
    function sortModel()
        {
            for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                for(var j=0; j<count; j++)
                {
                    if(get(i).year < get(j).year)
                        move(i,j,1)
                    else if(get(i).year === get(j).year && get(i).month < get(j).month)
                        move(i,j,1)
                    else if(get(i).year === get(j).year && get(i).month === get(j).month && get(i).day < get(j).day)
                        move(i,j,1)
                    else if(get(i).year === get(j).year && get(i).month === get(j).month && get(i).day === get(j).day && get(i).hour < get(j).hour)
                        move(i,j,1)
                    else if(get(i).year === get(j).year && get(i).month === get(j).month && get(i).day === get(j).day && get(i).hour === get(j).hour && get(i).minute < get(j).minute)
                        move(i,j,1)
                }
            }
        }

       Component.onCompleted: sortModel()
}
```

Здесь идет добавление будильника:

**AlarmDialog.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Dialog {
    id: alarmDialog
    title: "Add new alarm"
    modal: true
    standardButtons: DialogButtonBox.Ok | DialogButtonBox.Cancel

    property AlarmModel alarmModel

    function formatNumber(number) {
        return number < 10 && number >= 0 ? "0" + number : number.toString()
    }    
    onAccepted: {
        alarmModel.insert(alarmModel.count,{
            "hour": hoursTumbler.currentIndex,
            "minute": minutesTumbler.currentIndex,
            "day": dayTumbler.currentIndex + 1,
            "month": monthTumbler.currentIndex + 1,
            "year": yearTumbler.years[yearTumbler.currentIndex],
            "activated": true,
            "label": "",
            "repeat": false, 
            "daysToRepeat": [
                { "dayOfWeek": 0, "repeat": false },
                { "dayOfWeek": 1, "repeat": false },
                { "dayOfWeek": 2, "repeat": false },
                { "dayOfWeek": 3, "repeat": false },
                { "dayOfWeek": 4, "repeat": false },
                { "dayOfWeek": 5, "repeat": false },
                { "dayOfWeek": 6, "repeat": false }
            ],
        }) 
        alarmModel.sortModel()
    }  

    onRejected: alarmDialog.close()


    contentItem: RowLayout {
        RowLayout {
            id: rowTumbler

            Tumbler {
                id: hoursTumbler
                model: 24
                delegate: TumblerDelegate {
                    text: formatNumber(modelData)
                }
            }
            Tumbler {
                id: minutesTumbler
                model: 60
                delegate: TumblerDelegate {
                    text: formatNumber(modelData)
                }
            }
        }

        RowLayout {
            id: datePicker

            Layout.leftMargin: 20

            property alias dayTumbler: dayTumbler
            property alias monthTumbler: monthTumbler
            property alias yearTumbler: yearTumbler

            readonly property var days: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

            Tumbler {
                id: dayTumbler

                function updateModel() {
                    // Populate the model with days of the month. For example: [0, ..., 30]
                    var previousIndex = dayTumbler.currentIndex
                    var array = []
                    var newDays = datePicker.days[monthTumbler.currentIndex]
                    for (var i = 1; i <= newDays; ++i)
                        array.push(i)
                    dayTumbler.model = array
                    dayTumbler.currentIndex = Math.min(newDays - 1, previousIndex)
                }

                Component.onCompleted: updateModel()

                delegate: TumblerDelegate {
                    text: formatNumber(modelData)
                }
            }
            Tumbler {
                id: monthTumbler

                onCurrentIndexChanged: dayTumbler.updateModel()

                model: 12
                delegate: TumblerDelegate {
                    text: window.locale.standaloneMonthName(modelData, Locale.ShortFormat)
                }
            }
            Tumbler {
                id: yearTumbler

                // This array is populated with the next three years. For example: [2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]
                readonly property var years: (function() {
                    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
                    return [0, 1, 2, 3].map(function(value) { return value + currentYear ; })
                })()

                model: years
                delegate: TumblerDelegate {
                    text: formatNumber(modelData)
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример из официальной документации
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdoc-tutorials-alarms-example.html